# How to upgrade rails 3.2.13 application to rails 4.2 including gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am working a task where I have to upgrade the Rails 3.2.13 application to Rails 4.2.4 application. Also there are almost 68 gems with older versions like

```
gem 'carrierwave', "~> 0.5.3"
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.3'
gem "client_side_validations", "3.0.12"
#gem 'paper_trail', "~> 2.2.2"
gem 'devise', '~> 1.4.5'
gem "cancan", "~> 1.6.5"
gem 'nested_scaffold', '~> 0.1.0'
gem 'formatize', '~> 1.1.0'
gem 'rails_autolink', '~> 1.0.6'
```

how can I change this? Anyone please tell me the process from where I have to start?

Answer (score 1):

I recently updated one of our massive applications to Rails 4 from Rails 3, and I can assure you, it isn't fun.

- That being said, your best move on this is as follows: Make sure you have a solid enough test suite on your code base.  This will make things a lot easier for you down the road.
- Update the core rails gems first.
- Manually do your gems one at a time.  Use [rubygems.org](http://www.rubygems.org) to find the most recent supported version for your application version
- Be sure to go through and make the changes for each of them gem configurations as you move through them.
- Once you have a full bundle working run your test suite.  You will find MANY issues within these to get you to a somewhat working state.

Like I said, I just went through this and it was certainly interesting to do on the application I was working on.